# Custom Plugin: Point to `template_directory`

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am creating a plugin and I want to load the content of a folder.
The folder is in the `themes` folder.

I can't seem to point to the folder from the plugin.
I can do it if the `.php` file is also in the `themes` folder with:

```
$path = dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/{foldername}';
```

This is what I have:

```
$path = dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/brands_icons';

if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    $bgis = array();
    while ($bgis[] = readdir($handle));
    sort($bgis);
    closedir($handle);
}

$blacklist = array('','.','..');
$search = '.png';
$replace = '';
foreach ($bgis as $bgi) {
        if (!in_array($bgi, $blacklist)) {
            echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/{foldername}/'.$bgi   .'" />';
        }
}
```

The warning I get is:

```
Warning: opendir(http://www.website.com/themes/{themename}/images/{foldername})
[function.opendir]: failed to open dir: not implemented in .../wp-content/plugins/{pluginname}/
custom-meta-box-template.php on line 208
```

------------------------------------
UPDATE:
I have fixed it with:

```
$path = ( ABSPATH .'/wp-content/themes/{themename}/images/{foldername}' );
```

I have no idea if this is the correct way to do this. So some feedback/thoughts would be appreciated!

M.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [directory constants](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants) WordPress defines. `WP_CONTENT_DIR` will give you the folder path, whereas `WP_CONTENT_URL` will give you the url to the folder.